# Finding rows with multiple properties

Tags: sql

I have a table where the structure is:

```
+----+-------+----------+
| ID | Class | Names    |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  | Paper |    Ed    |
+----+-------+----------+
| 2  | Glass |    Pete  |
+----+-------+----------+
| 3  | Glass |    Ed    |
+----+-------+----------+
| 4  | Rock  |    Fred  |
+----+-------+----------+
```

I want to find names who have a class of paper and glass. So in this little table it would return just:

```
+----+-------+----------+
| ID | Class | Names    |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  | Paper |    Ed    |
+----+-------+----------+
| 3  | Glass |    Ed    |
+----+-------+----------+
```

However the name can't be part of the query. It has to be find names where class = paper and class = glass. So I only want names that have both paper and glass.

Simplified the SQL would be:

SELECT `Names` FROM table WHERE `Class` = Paper AND `Class` = Glass

Obviously this doesn't work thou as a row only has one class value.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Names 
FROM table 
WHERE Class IN ('Paper','Glass') -- list of Class
GROUP BY Names
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2              -- number of class
```

in the case that `Class` is not unique in every `names`, a `DISTINCT` is require to count only unique value.

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Class) = 2
```